# Homebrew: installed sleepwatcher, wanted to run suggested service command, got "Formula not installed"

Tags: sleep, homebrew

I installed sleepwatcher using Homebrew. Everything worked well as it seems, here's the output:

```
josh@Macbuech:~/Documents/Work/Access4All/projects/a4aa2/src$ brew install sleepwatcher
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/sleepwatcher-2.2.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring sleepwatcher-2.2.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
For SleepWatcher to work, you will need to read the following:

  /usr/local/Cellar/sleepwatcher/2.2/ReadMe.rtf

Ignore information about installing the binary and man page,
but read information regarding setup of the launchd files which
are installed here:

  /usr/local/Cellar/sleepwatcher/2.2/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility-localuser.plist
  /usr/local/Cellar/sleepwatcher/2.2/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility.plist

These are the examples provided by the author.

To have launchd start sleepwatcher now and restart at login:
  brew services start sleepwatcher
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/sleepwatcher/2.2: 8 files, 53.3K
```

I wanted to run the service as suggested in the output, but got the following error:

```
josh@Macbuech:~/Documents/Work/Access4All/projects/a4aa2/src$ brew services start sleepwatcher
==> Tapping homebrew/services
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services'...
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 0), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Tapped 0 formulae (32 files, 46.4K)
Error: Formula `sleepwatcher` not installed, #startup_plist not implemented or no plist file found
josh@Macbuech:~/Documents/Work/Access4All/projects/a4aa2/src$
```

I'm unsure now. Did I miss something important? I read the README but it's confusing to me, I have no experience with launchd, daemons, services...

I want sleepwatcher to always run on my computer so it executes `~/.sleep` and `~/.wakeup` when going to sleep or wake up.

**Update**

I made sure that `brew service` is available, but didn't make it work.

```
josh@Macbuech:~/Documents/Work/MuheimWebdesign/tests/tilt$ brew tap homebrew/services
josh@Macbuech:~/Documents/Work/MuheimWebdesign/tests/tilt$ brew services start sleepwatcher
Error: Formula `sleepwatcher` not installed, #startup_plist not implemented or no plist file found
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `brew service` first? If not, you will need to do it just for one time,

`brew tap homebrew/services`

After that you should be able to

`brew services start sleepwatcher`

without any error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work out, look at my updated question.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  Now I would suspect if your user doesn't have the privilege to drive the linking of plist file.  Just for testing, can you try with `sudo brew services sleepwatcher` and see if the output is different?

Comment: Giving me the same error.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, now probably need to unwrap brew services and run those behind the scene stuff manually to understand more, please try the following `ln -sfv /usr/local/Cellar/sleepwatcher/2.2/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents` and then `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility.plist`

Comment: Thank you. I executed both commands, and they seemed to work as expected. But `brew services start sleepwatcher` still returns `Formula `sleepwatcher` not installed`.

Comment: Oh I see, actually I am now out of ideas, what I can suggest to proceed further are 1) try to install another services (say, mysql) to tell if it is a homebrew or sleepwatcher problem, 2) try your luck at Ask Different where there are more Apple experts around and 3) issue a ticket at the [official source](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues)

Comment: I wasn't able to solve the problem with Homebrew, but after doing a `chmod 700 ~/.sleep` (as written here: https://www.kodiakskorner.com/log/258), sleepwatcher seems to work and do its duty.

Comment: Interestingly, after a restart, it doesn't work anymore. The `.sleep` file isn't executed, but `$ launchctl list | grep sleep` shows me that `de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher` is a running process. Any idea?